# C# find most occurring value in a list of strings

Tags: c#, linq

I've very simple list like

```
List<string> mostFrequent = new List<string>()
{
   "Hot",
   "Sunny",
   "Windy",
   "Sunny",
   "Rainy"
}
```

If I want to find the most occurring value in the list, I use the following code.

```
var groupsWithCounts = from s in mostFrequent
group s by s into g
select new { 
    Item = g.Key, 
    Count = g.Count()
};

var groupsSorted = groupsWithCounts.OrderByDescending(g => g.Count);
string mostFrequest = groupsSorted.First().Item;
```

Using this, I get the most frequent value (Sunny) in the mostFrequent variable. But If this List's item is null twice, then it becomes null. Such as in this case

```
List<string> mostFrequent = new List<string>()
{
   null,
   "Sunny",
   null,
   "Sunny",
   "Rainy"
}
```

I still want to the value of mostFrequent as Sunny. But it becomes null. Any idea that how to get most frequent item in the above list?

Comment: Use `where` to get rid of `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var notnull = mostFrequent.Where(f=>f!=null);
```

this will strip out all null values

Comment: Thanks, I resolved my problem using your answer combined with @Kiksen. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the bellow to get the most frequent item

```
var item = mostFrequent.Where(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c)).GroupBy(a => a).OrderByDescending(b => b.Key[1].ToString()).First().Key;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry :) Didn't read it propper. 
Here is the awnser.

```
var most = (from i in mostFrequent
                     where i != null
                    group i by i into grp
                    orderby grp.Count() descending
                    select grp.Key).First();
```

Or other way like this:

```
var most = mostFrequent.GroupBy(i => i).OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count()).Select(grp => grp.Key).Where(x => x != null).First();
```